# как включить обычный класс в DI

Tags: java, di

собственно сабж, как из обычного класса использовать `@Inject`?
как я понимаю для этого класс должен находится контексте или иными словами контекст должен знать про классе...

но как это реализуется не совсем понятно, пробовал даже так:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "myBean", name = "myBean")
public class MyBEAN implements MyBeanInterface {
```

и следовательно в самом классе

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
MyBEAN mbi = (MyBEAN) ctx.lookup("myBean");
```

но не помогло

Comment: для java ee пишите?

Comment: да, можете посоветовать что нибудь?

Comment: Не понимаю фразу как использовать `@Inject` Вешаете аннотации на поля и методы, в процессе создания бина контейнер позаботится об остальном - найдет соотвествующие бины и засетит их, а если бинов с таким типом нет то он об это сообщит

Comment: дело в том что у меня есть тестовый класс
    `public class StChart {
    @Inject
    private MyBeanInterface mbi;

    public void sendChartWithStart() {
        System.out.println("MyBeanInterface StChart>> " + mbi);
    }`
так вот тут я получаю нул потому что это обычный класс...

Comment: Так объявите его бином, в java ee нужно ваше приложение запаковать war и задеплоить в     application server, вы же это делаете?

Comment: объявить бином это типа @Bean?
естественно и вар и деплой в  сервер происходит... ибо откуда столько вопросов...

Comment: А контекст для бинов прописан?

Comment: вот тут можете чуть подробнее?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/default-cdi-enablement-in-java-ee-7

Comment: так у меня и `bean-discovery-mode="all"`

Comment: Расположение файла правильное? зайдите в админку или логи AS  и посмотрите какие там у него есть бины проинициализированные

Comment: ну если я вас понял правильно то там только один, тот который я объявил бином
`@Stateless(mappedName = "myBean", name = "myBean")
public class MyBEAN implements MyBeanInterface {`

Comment: у вас как минимум должно быть два бина, один который инджектится другой в который инджектят

Comment: в этом бине у меня реализуется все операции над объектами т.е. КРУД операции, а дальше как? можете чуть подробнее?

Comment: Как это работает? все объявляется бинами, далее когда di подымает контекст он сканирует классы и ищет бины, в зависимости от их скоупа, инициализирует либо откладывает инициализацию до тех пор пока они не понадобятся. В процессе создания бина, инджектит другие бины в него.

Comment: т.е. объект `public class StChart {
    @Inject
    private MyBeanInterface mbi;`
аннотировать @RequestScope или ещё чем то? т.к. просто аннотации @Bean нет... или вообще @Stateless

Comment: иными словами как заставить контекст чтоб знал про бейсик класс?

Comment: Зависит от бизнес логики, но в целом да, идея такая

Comment: в том то и дело не работают они или я пишу не в том месте...